# In java if i extend a class and make it's object in main function, will there be any object of parent class is created in heap?

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm, heap-memory

```
class parent{
   int x=10;

   public void show()
   {
   }
}

class child extends parent{
  int y=20;

  public void display()
  {
  }
}

class test{
p.s.v main(String args[])
{
  child c=new child();
}
}
```

what will be there in **heap memory**?

1.object of parent and object of child **separated**?

2.object of child class having parent object **inside** it?

3.only object of child class having class **info of parent class** not object of parent class?

Comment: The answer is 3. See the duplicate question for ways to check the contents of your heap.

Comment: A `child` object **is a** `parent` object.